# How do I use the Sed command to match on everything between two patterns?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

This is an example of a row pf data from the CSV file that I'm parsing.

```
"Monday, July 3, 2023 at 9:12:34 PM GMT+0:00","Answer 1","Answer 2","Answer 3"
```

I'm trying to remove the part reading ", 2023 at 9:12:34 PM GMT+0:00", so it looks like this:

```
"Monday, July 3","Answer 1","Answer 2","Answer 3"
```

The timestamp data is going to be a different value for each row in the CSV file, so I can't simply hardcode it.

When I try this command, nothing happens to the file. I'm not sure why,

```
sed -i 's/, 2023[","]/","/g' example.csv
```

I have a feeling that I'm overlooking something simple.

Answer (score 0):

`[","]` matches a *single* character that matches either `"`, or `,`, or `"`.

You presumably want to match a *sequence* of characters that is not `"`, and replace it with nothing. So (always test without `-i` first)

```
sed -i 's/, 2023[^"]*//' example.csv
```

You might want to consider using a tool that understands the CSV format though - for example, with [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
mlr --csv -N --quote-all put '$1 = sub($1,", 2023.*", "")'  example.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -i.bak 's/,[^,]*"/"/' input_file
"Monday, July 3","Answer 1","Answer 2","Answer 3"
```